# How to see what is the hosting directory of an IP?

Tags: linux, dns, server, directory, ip

I have the IP (212.1.215.59) and it is connected with my server. It seems to be hosted on empty directory, because when you visit http://212.1.215.59/ you see "Index of /". How do I find the directory, so I can upload index?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is default host and linux server,

What I see from your web server's response headers it is apache.

Default directory for apache is /var/www/html

You can try to execute following command to see the document root

```
 grep -R '^DocumentRoot' /etc/httpd/ 2>/dev/null ; grep -R '^DocumentRoot' /etc/apache2/ 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: I can't execute the command, because I don't have access to SSH. There is no such directory "var".

Comment: do you connect with ftp ? It depends on hosting but usually folder names in your home directory are : public_html , html , www, public, web

Comment: I have www and public_html, but http://212.1.215.59/ seems as not being on the main directory. I saw it while issuing SSL for the subdomain tc.gamingprouk.net (/home/g*******7/public_html/tc.gamingprouk.net)

Comment: Most likely you are sharing this ip address with other hosts (name-based virtual host), so you can't change the contents of the ip directly but only yourdomain.net and its subdomains. You can read more about name-based virtual host from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html